# .htaccess rewrite index.php?f=test to /test/

Tags: apache, .htaccess

how can i rewrite `/index.php?f=test` to `/test`

example : `domain.com/?f=test` to `domain.com/test`

and I want to receive in PHP data as GET Request

```
<?php 

$file = $_GET['f'];

// if url was domain.com/test/ $file must be test 

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Can you please share What  you  have tried?

Comment: the latest one is RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+) index.php?f=$1 

 and php result is index

Comment: Please dont post your code in the comment area. edit your question to post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **index** you are getting on your php file is because of the unconditional rule. your rule is causing an infinite redirect/double redirect. You need to exclude your existent files from the rule .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?f=$1
```